# keyword @relation expected weka java

Tags: java, exception, attributes, weka, k-means

i implements a kmeans algorithm in java using weka

so i have this code java that i have copy from: [Cannot handle any class attribute! kmeans java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706595/cannot-handle-any-class-attribute-kmeans-java)

```
public class demo {
    public demo() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        BufferedReader breader = null;
        breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "D:/workspace_java/JenaTutorial/movie.arff"));
        Instances Train = new Instances(breader);
        //Train.setClassIndex(Train.numAttributes() - 1); // comment out this line
        SimpleKMeans kMeans = new SimpleKMeans();
        kMeans.setSeed(10);
        kMeans.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true);
        kMeans.setNumClusters(3);
        kMeans.buildClusterer(Train);
        int[] assignments = kMeans.getAssignments();
        int i = 0;
        for (int clusterNum : assignments) {
            System.out.printf("Instance %d -> Cluster %d", i, clusterNum);
            i++;
        }
        breader.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new demo();
    }
}
```

and it is un extract of my file "movie.arff":

```
@attribute title string
@attribute annee string
@attribute genre string
@attribute genre1 string
@attribute genre2 string
@attribute genre3 string
@attribute actor string
@attribute actor1 string
@attribute actor2 string
@attribute actor3 string
@attribute actor4 string
@attribute actor5 string
@attribute actor6 string
@attribute actor7 string
@attribute actor8 string
@attribute actor9 string
@attribute writer string
@attribute writer1 string
@attribute writer2 string
@attribute writer3 string
@attribute writer4 string
@attribute writer5 string
@attribute writer6 string
@attribute writer7 string
@attribute writer8 string
@attribute writer9 string


@data
'Toy Story','1995','Adventure','Animation','Children','Comedy','Fantasy','Tom Hanks','Wallace Shawn','John Ratzenberger','John Morris ','Annie Potts','Don Rickles','Laurie Metcalf','Tim Allen','Jim Varney','Erik von Detten','Joel Cohen (writer)','Joss Whedon','Andrew Stanton','Alec Sokolow',

'Jumanji','1995','Adventure','Children','Fantasy','?','Robin Williams','Kirsten Dunst','David Alan Grier','Bonnie Hunt','Bebe Neuwirth','Jonathan Hyde','?','?','?','?','Greg Taylor (author)','Jonathan Hensleigh','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','Greg Taylor (author)','Jonathan Hensleigh','?','?',


'Grumpier Old Men','1995','Comedy','Romance','?','?','Sophia Loren','Walter Matthau','Jack Lemmon','Ann-Margret','Burgess Meredith','Daryl Hannah','Ann Morgan Guilbert','Kevin Pollak','?','?','Mark Steven Johnson','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','Mark Steven Johnson','?','?','?',


'Waiting to Exhale','1995','Comedy','Drama','Romance','?','Whitney Houston','Lela Rochon','Loretta Devine','Angela Bassett','?','?','?','?','?','?','Ronald Bass','Terry McMillan','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','Ronald Bass','Terry McMillan','?','?',


'Father of the Bride Part II','1995','Comedy','?','?','?','Steve Martin','Martin Short','Diane Keaton','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','Charles Shyer','Albert Hackett','Frances Goodrich','Nancy Meyers','?','?','?','?','?','?','Charles Shyer','Albert Hackett','Frances Goodrich','Nancy Meyers',
```

but in excecution i have this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: keyword @relation expected, read Token[@attribute], line 1
at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader$ArffReader.errorMessage(ArffLoader.java:354)
at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader$ArffReader.readHeader(ArffLoader.java:806)
at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader$ArffReader.<init>(ArffLoader.java:204)
at weka.core.Instances.<init>(Instances.java:135)
at wakaproject.demo.<init>(demo.java:14)
at wakaproject.demo.main(demo.java:31)
```

can you help me please!

Comment: Try to load your file in weka explorer, you will get same error. Fix your arff file so that it can be loaded in weka explorer, then try to write java code.

Comment: Reread the **arff format specifications**. Your file is not a proper arff file.

Comment: Also understand that k-means can only use **numerical data**. As the name suggests, it needs to compute the **mean**. What is the mean of "Toy Story" and "Adventure"?

Answer (score 1):

as it says the file has to start with @relation not @attribute

Answer (score 0):

I have face the similar issue using Java program.

Program always expects valid *.arff file format like below:

```
@relation **<file name>**
@attribute <attribute1-name> ...
@attribute <attribute2-name> ...

@data
1,1
1,2
1,1.333333
...
...
```

In case you are facing similar exception using CSV file. Please check here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280612446_Using_WEKA_in_your_java_code_Clustering